# mod_rewrite redirects only index page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The problem is that following .htaccess syntax:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} robots.txt$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bd-spb\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xn----8sbbkdenhe5aqs7a.xn--p1ai/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bd-spb\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xn----8sbbkdenhe5aqs7a.xn--p1ai/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Redirects only index page. So if I go to [bd-spb.ru](http://bd-spb.ru) I will get [бизнес-диалог.рф](http://%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3.%D1%80%D1%84), but if I go for example [here](http://bd-spb.ru/%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-2/) its not redirects me [here](http://xn----8sbbkdenhe5aqs7a.xn--p1ai/%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-2/).

How to make this happens?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? `http://bd-spb.ru/foo` will get redirected to `http://xn----8sbbkdenhe5aqs7a.xn--p1ai/foo`

Comment: Yes i want make it work exactly as you sayd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} robots\.txt$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bd-spb\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xn----8sbbkdenhe5aqs7a.xn--p1ai/$1 [R=301,L,B]
```

Comment: Its still not redirecting [link](http://bd-spb.ru/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3/)

Comment: Its needed to be saved in UTF-8 Without BOM charset. Then it works just fine. Thank you.